# IBM DB2 9.7 free monitoring tools

Tags: db2, profile, monitor

Any good advice on what tools to use to monitor a DB2 database? I have used the db2top command but was wondering if there are more verbose tools out there. Our DB is running on Linux64

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As tools, you can use the memory tracker db2mtrk, Problem determination db2pd. But also you can use many other things, such as:

- function tables
- administrative views
- get snapshot
- create and active event monitors.

It really depends on what you are goin to do.

Also, the IBM Optim Performance Expert is a good tool to find bttlenecks or issues in the Database. Also the DBI panther brother. And finally the Data Studio Web Console is a basic tool to monitor few elements.

What do you want to monitor? probably with the help of a cron that executes a script you can do many things.